# Sharepoint Bulk Upload using JAVA

Tags: java, sharepoint, http-post, httpconnection

I have an existing API to Single List to the the SharePoint API. New requirement is to upload multiple data using the same API. we are Using NTLM authentication the access. In the same code when I tried to pass multiple item it is still saving the only first Item. I have went through the multiple post for the problem and was not able to solve it one of which is [Bulk upload share point](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/11/29/sharepoint-bulk-insert-using-java-program/), I tried this but the authentication here is different, please suggest me how can I achieve this in my code.
Below is the code for uploading 1 list item.

```
public class RESTApiUtil {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String jsonInputString = "{ \"__metadata\": { \"type\": \"SP.Data.Raffle_x005f_Draw_x005f_RegistrationListItem\" },"
            + "\"Title\": \"title1\",\"Employee_Email\": \"employee1@gmail.com\","
            + "\"Employee_Name\": \"empName\",\"Registration_Date\": \"12-06-2019\",\"Employee_No\": \"123\"},"+
            "{ \"__metadata\": { \"type\": \"SP.Data.Raffle_x005f_Draw_x005f_RegistrationListItem\" },"
            + "\"Title\": \"title2\",\"Employee_Email\": \"employee2@gmail.com\","
            + "\"Employee_Name\": \"empName2\",\"Registration_Date\": \"12-06-2019\",\"Employee_No\": \"1234\"}";

         System.out.println(callPostAPI(
         "http://host/_api/contextinfo",
         "http://host/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Registration')/items",
         "userName", "password",
         "domain",jsonInputString));

    }


    public static String callPostAPI(String digestUrl, String postApiUrl, final String userName, final String password,
            final String domain, String postBody) {
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            String requestDigest = getRequestDigest(digestUrl, postApiUrl, userName, password, domain,"");
            String cookie = getCookieValue(postApiUrl, userName, password, domain, requestDigest, "");
            if(cookie!=null&&!"".equals(cookie)) {
                requestDigest = getRequestDigest(digestUrl, postApiUrl, userName, password, domain,cookie);
                if (requestDigest != null && !"".equals(requestDigest)) {
                    response.append(sendPostRequest(postApiUrl, userName, password, domain, requestDigest, postBody));
                } else {
                    response.append("Failed To Get Request Digest");
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private static String getRequestDigest(String urlStr,String postApiUrl, final String userName, final String password, final String domain,String cookie) {

        String response = "";
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {

            int port = 80;
            String serverName = "";

            int endIndex = 0;
            int index = urlStr.indexOf("/");
            int count=0;
            while(index >= 0) {
               count++;
               index = urlStr.indexOf("/", index+1);
               if(count==2) {
                   endIndex = index;
                   break;
               }
            }
            String splitedServerName = urlStr.substring(urlStr.indexOf("//")+2,endIndex);
            serverName = splitedServerName;
            if(splitedServerName.contains(":")) {
                serverName = splitedServerName.split(":")[0];
                port = Integer.valueOf(splitedServerName.split(":")[1]);
            }

            NTCredentials creds = new NTCredentials(userName, password, domain, domain);
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(serverName, port), creds);

            List authpref = new ArrayList();
            authpref.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM);

            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(AuthPNames.TARGET_AUTH_PREF, authpref);
            HttpHost target = new HttpHost(serverName, port, "http");
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlStr);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            if(!"".equals(cookie))
                httpPost.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);

            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(target,httpPost, localContext);


            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            InputStream stream = response1.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            String str = "";
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(str);
            }
            in.close();

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(output.toString());
            JSONObject obj1 = obj.getJSONObject("d");
            JSONObject obj2 = obj1.getJSONObject("GetContextWebInformation");
            response = obj2.getString("FormDigestValue");


            return response;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }

    private static String sendPostRequest(String postUrl, String userName, String password, String domain, String digest,
            String postBody) throws IOException {

        String response = "";
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {

            int port = 80;
            String serverName = "";

            int endIndex = 0;
            int index = postUrl.indexOf("/");
            int count=0;
            while(index >= 0) {
               count++;
               index = postUrl.indexOf("/", index+1);
               if(count==2) {
                   endIndex = index;
                   break;
               }
            }
            String splitedServerName = postUrl.substring(postUrl.indexOf("//")+2,endIndex);
            serverName = splitedServerName;
            if(splitedServerName.contains(":")) {
                serverName = splitedServerName.split(":")[0];
                port = Integer.valueOf(splitedServerName.split(":")[1]);
            }

            NTCredentials creds = new NTCredentials(userName, password, domain, domain);
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(serverName, port), creds);

            List authpref = new ArrayList();
            authpref.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM);

            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(AuthPNames.TARGET_AUTH_PREF, authpref);
            HttpHost target = new HttpHost(serverName, port, "http");
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postUrl);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            httpPost.setHeader("X-RequestDigest", digest);

            System.out.println("postbody "+postBody);
                                //Jar file: json-simple-1.1.1.jar

        /*  String[] data= postBody.split("},");
            for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                String str=data[i].toString();
                System.out.println("Struing "+str);
             }*/


            StringEntity params =new StringEntity(postBody);
            httpPost.setEntity(params);


            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(target,httpPost, localContext);

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            InputStream stream = response1.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            String str = "";
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(str);
            }

            return output.toString();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }



    private static String getCookieValue(String postUrl, String userName, String password, String domain, String digest,
            String postBody) throws IOException {

        String response = "";
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {

            int port = 80;
            String serverName = "";

            int endIndex = 0;
            int index = postUrl.indexOf("/");
            int count=0;
            while(index >= 0) {
               count++;
               index = postUrl.indexOf("/", index+1);
               if(count==2) {
                   endIndex = index;
                   break;
               }
            }
            String splitedServerName = postUrl.substring(postUrl.indexOf("//")+2,endIndex);
            serverName = splitedServerName;
            if(splitedServerName.contains(":")) {
                serverName = splitedServerName.split(":")[0];
                port = Integer.valueOf(splitedServerName.split(":")[1]);
            }

            NTCredentials creds = new NTCredentials(userName, password, domain, domain);
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(serverName, port), creds);

            List authpref = new ArrayList();
            authpref.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM);

            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(AuthPNames.TARGET_AUTH_PREF, authpref);
            HttpHost target = new HttpHost(serverName, port, "http");
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postUrl);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            httpPost.setHeader("X-RequestDigest", digest);

            StringEntity params =new StringEntity(postBody);
            httpPost.setEntity(params);

            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(target,httpPost, localContext);

             Header[] headers = response1.getAllHeaders();
                for (Header header: headers) {
                    if(header.getName()!=null) {
                    if("Set-Cookie".equals(header.getName())) {
                        response = header.getValue().substring(0, header.getValue().indexOf(";"));
                        if(response.contains("WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated"))
                            break;
                    }
                    }
                }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }

}
```

**UPDATE**
I have updated the code where I am creating the batch data as per the post and trying to pass that in the setEntity() method.

```
StringEntity params =new StringEntity(getData(postBody,postUrl));
            httpPost.setEntity(params);  
private static String getData(String postBody, String postUrl) {
        //generate uniqueId for a batch boundary
        String batchGuid = generateUUID();

        //generate uniqueId for each item to be inserted
        String changeSetId = generateUUID();

        //Begin of: Prepare Bulk Request Format for SharePoint Bulk-Insert-Query ----------------       
        String batchContents = "";
        try {               
            //Parse the output-count JSON           
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(postBody);                      
            String[] data= JSONObject.getNames(obj);
            JSONArray jsonArr = obj.toJSONArray(new JSONArray(data));   //Returned string in JSonArray, so convert it to JSonArray

            //SharePoint URL to insert one item     
            String endpoint_Insert = postUrl;       

            //Start: changeset to insert data ----------            
            String batchCnt_Insert = "";
            for(int i=0; i<jsonArr.length(); i++){              
                JSONObject jsonObj =  new JSONObject();
                jsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonArr.get(i);                      //get ith array object  
                String title  = (jsonObj.get("tytle")).toString();  
                String employeeEmail = (jsonObj.get("employeEmail")).toString();    
                String employeeName= (jsonObj.get("employeeName")).toString();
                String employeeNo= (jsonObj.get("employeeNo")).toString();
                String registrationDate =(jsonObj.get("registrationDate")).toString();

                //Start:create INSERT-Statement for one Item ---------------------------                
                String request = "{ \"__metadata\": { \"type\": \"SP.Data.Raffle_x005f_Draw_x005f_RegistrationListItem\" },"
                        + "\"Title\": \""+title+"\",\"Employee_Email\": \""+employeeEmail+"\","
                        + "\"Employee_Name\": \""+employeeName+"\",\"Registration_Date\": \""+registrationDate+"\",\"Employee_No\": \""+employeeNo+"\"}";

                batchCnt_Insert = batchCnt_Insert 
                        + "--changeset_" + changeSetId + "\n"
                        + "Content-Type: application/http" + "\n"
                        + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + "\n"
                        + "" + "\n"
                        + "POST " + endpoint_Insert + " \n"
                        + "Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose" + "\n"
                        + "" + "\n"
                        + request + "\n"
                        + "" + "\n";        
                //END:create INSERT-Statement for one Item ------------------------------
            }
            //END:   changeset to insert data ----------

            batchCnt_Insert = batchCnt_Insert + "--changeset_" + changeSetId + "--\n";

            //create batch for creating items           
            batchContents = "--batch_" + batchGuid + "\n"
                        + "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"changeset_" + changeSetId + "\"\n"
                        + "Content-Length: " + batchCnt_Insert.length() + "\n"
                        + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + "\n"
                        + "" + "\n"
                        + batchCnt_Insert + "\n";
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return batchContents;
    }
    private static String generateUUID(){           
        //Generates a GUID-like string, used in HTTP batches
        //Generating unique IDs | The identifiers generated by UUID are actually universally unique identifiers.            
        UUID idOne = UUID.randomUUID();
        String idOne_Str =  String.valueOf(idOne);
        return idOne_Str;
    }
```

and I am getting following error.

```
postbody {"__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.RegistrationListItem" },"Title": "New title","Name": "test@gmail.com","Email": "test"},{"__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.RegistrationListItem" },"Title": "New title","Name": "test@gmail.com","Email": "test"}
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A node of type 'EndOfInput' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the start of an entry. A 'StartObject' node was expected."}}}
```

Comment: You just need to construct data in the format required for batch insert as explained in the post you have shared - NTLM authentication is not going to make any difference and should remain as is - if you can share error you are getting after changing this to support bulk insert - it will be easier to provide inputs.

Comment: I have updated the code the with the error I am getting

Comment: Posts suggest the space after "Title": could cause this issue - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/261091/sharepoint-post-rest-api-returning-error-code-400

Comment: as you can see the code there is not space in my KEY names

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not posting data in the format as required by Sharepoint REST API.

**Expected format -**

> --batch_b27de00f-98f2-4dcb-9fd4-efa8f57380f4 Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>   boundary="changeset_85050752-ccb7-40d1-a883-2ae3ac0c100c"
>   Content-Length: 1161 Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> --changeset_85050752-ccb7-40d1-a883-2ae3ac0c100c Content-Type: application/http Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> POST
>   https://ClientDomain.sharepoint.com/teams/SPdev/AlertsCount/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('AlertCount')/Items
>   HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
>
> {"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.AlertCountListItem"},"Title":"213323","PeningCount":"3"}
>
> --changeset_85050752-ccb7-40d1-a883-2ae3ac0c100c Content-Type: application/http Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> POST
>   https://ClientDomain.sharepoint.com/teams/SPdev/AlertsCount/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('AlertCount')/Items
>   HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
>
> {"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.AlertCountListItem"},"Title":"231499","PeningCount":"9"}

Few required parts seem missing from the code sample you have posted - 
For eg. Where are you specifying MIME type as multipart/mixed? Why are you not using $batch endpoints in URL?

Sharepoint rest APIs have a strict request/response format which you have to adhere to for it to work. To understand the specifications please refer detailed documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis).
This [link](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/11/29/sharepoint-bulk-insert-using-java-program/) which you are following has sample code on how to create a batch insert